# Why can we say "drink" but we can't say "drinks"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Why can we use the first sentence and not the second one?

- *after take off, we will have food and drink*
- *after take off, we will have food and drinks*

Which is more correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you can.

> - We will have food and drink
> - We will have food and drinks

Both are acceptable, however, the phrase [**food and drink** is more common than **food and drinks**](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=41392503).

Comment: Well , I have been doing a research online , seems like everyone says "drink" and never found anyone saying "drinks" , so what's the difference ?

Comment: _food and drink_ is more common, but _food and drinks_ is well-represented - see my update.

Comment: To me, _food and drink_ sounds like communally available, unlimited drinks, whereas _food and drinks_ seems applicable to individually doled out single servings, which is what you get on airplanes. Maybe the airlines see it the opposite way, thinking that if they said "drinks", passengers would expect more than one.

Answer (score 3):

"Food and drink" in American English refers to refreshments, or to the categories *comestibles* and *beverages*, whereas "food and drinks" refers to alcoholic beverages and light fare, that is, to an outing where one consumes these.

**Food and drink will be served at intermission|after the ceremony|etc.**

**The establishment is licensed to serve food and drink.**

**After work, let's all go out for food and drinks.**

Comment: "Drinks" always makes me think of cocktails, not beverages in general. +1 for mentioning alcoholic beverages.

Comment: http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2011/07/why-carbonated-beverages-are-called-soft-drinks/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. Because when you say 'food', it means food in 'general'. But then, 'foods' is what you'd use if you are talking about its various types.

> We were served with various types of foods and drinks

So, both are okay!

Comment: This is acceptable, but rare. Most of the time, we let _food_ be a plural noun: _There will be free food at the picnic._ When we include drinks, we often keep them both singular: _There will be free food and drink at the picnic_, although _free food and drinks_ is okay, too, as we would normally say, _There will be free drinks at the picnic_. _Food and drink_ is just a standard phrasing, possible because they sound good together as a pair. Checking for `food|foods and drink|drinks` in the Corpus shows 518 hits for _food and drink_, 108 for _food and drinks_, and only 40 for _foods and drinks_.

Comment: @J.R., it depends very much on the context. Food is a collective noun, so we are more likely to treat drink as a collective noun when it appears next to food. Used next to a plural noun like snacks, we prefer to use the plural of drinks.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snacks+and+drinks%2C+snacks+and+drink&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnacks%20and%20drinks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnacks%20and%20drink%3B%2Cc0